# Adhesive removal from my recently installed carpet

Tags: flooring, carpet

I recently installed some outdoor type - low profile carpet on my new office floor.  The adhesive used was TEC multi - purpose carpet adhesive.   The mastic bled through in a number of spots throughout the carpet (probably too much mastic). I was told the mastic would dry clear and therefore not be a problem.  It was installed this past Thursday, today is Sunday, I see no difference; even though the room is well heated with an added fan for good circulation.

How can I remove the bleed through mastic?

Answer (score 1):

This will vary depending on the particular product. For [TEC 706 Universal MultiPurpose Adhesive](http://media.hbfuller.com/documents/TEC++Universal+Multipurpose+Adhesive+PDS+0114.pdf), the product data sheet says:

**Clean-up**

Remove fresh adhesive from face of flooring with warm, soapy water. Dried adhesive must be removed with *mineral spirits*.